# Reactions count in WTelegramClient

Tags: telegram-api, tdlib, wtelegramclient

I am trying to implement script that will count reaction count for particular messages.

I already tried using `client.Messages_GetMessagesReactions()` and it return me `400 MSG_ID_INVALID`.

Current not working code part:

```cs
Dictionary<MessageBase, int> messages = new();
var step = 0;

while (history.Messages[0].Date >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7))
{
    await Task.Delay(500);

    foreach (var message in history.Messages)
    {
        var rec = await client.Messages_GetMessageReactionsList(new InputPeerUser(myself.ID, myself.access_hash), message.ID);
        if (rec.count >= 5)
            list.Add(message);
    }

    step += 20;
    history = await client.Messages_GetHistory(channel, 0, default, step, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figuret it out. Instead of using `Messages_GetMessagesReactions()` method i cast `message` (`MessageBase` class) to `Message` which have `reactions` property.